# Extending DS2408 IOs with MAX7219 or 74HC595

Tags: arduino

I have an idea of building a model traffic lights node with Arduino. One node should serve the whole intersection with all the lights from all directions.

I want to use a 1-wire DS2408 to identify the node by its factory set unique id and have its 8 IOs for different lights.

One node should have more lights (for difficult intersections more than 30-40).
I want to use some LED driver like MAX7219 or shift register like 74HC595 to extend these 8 IOs to 64.

Can something like this be done? Can I use DS2408 (1-Wire 8-Channel Addressable Switch) and extend its IOs?
Or what would you suggest?

I want to use this 1-wire protocol for better scalability and easy node addressing, let's say I want to build a model city with 100 intersections..
Thank you.

Comment: It would be better to ask it here: http://arduino.stackexchange.com/.

Comment: Or perhaps http://electronics.stackexchange.com ?